# Does this function have a limit at x=-1?

Tags: limits, functions

Graph here:

[image]

As the graph shows, the x=-1 only has the limit of $$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^{+}}\
$$
But the limit from the left does not seem available to me.

So, does this function have a limit at x=-1?

Thank you!

Comment: The left part of the function does not matter, as you are asking only for the limit approaching $-1$ on the right

Comment: @Wore Thanks. So the limit does exist for it?

Comment: Usually one analyses only the elements $x$ around $-1$ that are in the domain of the function to determine whether or not the limit exists. So, my answer would be yes, but it is merely a convention.

Comment: Yes, the limit exists! $\lim_{x\to-1}$ exists as well if one uses the lax version of the definition of the limit where you only consider $x$ values in the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute $\lim_{x\to a}f (x) $, we just need the expression of $f (x) $ near and arround the point $x=a $, for example in the intervall $(a-\eta,a+\eta) $.

in your case, if we look at the behavior of the function in $(-1,-1/2) $, it is clear that $$\lim_{x\to-1^+}f (x)=0=f (-1) .$$

the function is not defined on the left of the point $x=-1$, so the left limit $\lim_{x\to -1^-}f (x) $ cannot be defined.